# Как с генерировать csrf токен, используя HTML meta tag?

Tags: php, html, csrf

Нужно с генерировать  **csrf**  *токен* для POST запроса ,

Можно ли использовать *специальный*  HTML meta tag  и *как 
это сделать*?

Comment: Делаете в форме input с типом hidden в котором прописываете уникальный токен, например код сессии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSRF токен - это по сути строка которая крепится за пользователем, то есть просто создаете в сессии хеш, приведу пример для PHP7:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}
$token = $_SESSION['csrf_token']; // передаете на форму.
```

Далее я предпочитаю класть этот токен в `meta` для AJAX запросов и для форм делаете:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $token; ?>">
```

и потом при сабмите формы проверяете токен что в сессии с тем что пришел в форме.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял,  что  HTML meta tag не генерирует  csrf токен , тогда зачем он используется ?

Comment: Почитайте про CSRF защиту, HTML тут вообще не при чём, я писал в ответе что я кладу иногда в `meta` когда нужно через AJAX запросы слать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример: для начала надо создать функцию:

```
function generate_token(  ) {
    return $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = substr( str_shuffle( 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM' ), 0, 10 );
}
```

далее в форму добавляем дополнительное скрытое поле:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo generate_token(); ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_test" value="отправить" />
</form>
```

и когда проверяем данные, нужно сделать вот такую проверку:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit_test'] ) ) {
 if ( isset( $_SESSION['csrf_token'] ) && $_SESSION['csrf_token'] == @$_POST['csrf_token'] )
 {
   //Some actions
 }
}
```

Но есть один большой недостаток: $_SESSION['csrf_token'] будет генерироваться каждый раз, где есть форма. Если, например, существует форма авторизации на каждой странице, то на каждую форму генерируется новый токен, и если открыть несколько страниц и попробовать сделать авторизацию с первой страницы или вкладки, то токен, который будет передан в форме, не будет совпадать с тем , что есть в сессии. Но смысл защиты я думаю передан))

Вот ссылка: https://webzone.kz/publication/php-protection-from-csrf